# How to store audio files in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I would like to know how to store audio files in a mysql database so I can retrieve and play it on my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases are not intended for files in general. What I would do is simply store the file names, and store the files themselves on the database. Another (very risky and in my opinion useless option) is to convert the file into a string (ASCII) and then store the string.